# Time-table the nearest time

Tags: android

How to do a time-table the nearest time on a picture on the right? For me does not turn out, I am a novice. Please, help me.

[image]
--Fragment.java

```
public class DayFragment extends ListFragment {
String[] time = new String[] { "06:30","06:40","06:48","06:56","07:04","07:12","07:20","07:28","07:36", "07:44",
        "07:52", "08:00", "08:08", "08:16", "08:22", "08:31", "08:40", "08:50", "09:00", "09:10", "09:20",
        "09:30", "09:40", "09:50", "10:00", "10:10", "10:20", "10:30", "10:40", "10:50", "11:00", "11:10",
        "11:20", "11:30", "11:40", "11:50", "12:00", "12:10", "12:20", "12:30", "12:40", "12:50", "13:00",
        "13:10", "13:20", "13:30", "13:40", "13:50", "14:00", "14:10", "14:20", "14:30", "14:40", "14:50",
        "15:00", "15:10", "15:20", "15:30", "15:40", "15:50", "16:00", "16:10", "16:20", "16:30", "16:40", 
        "16:50", "17:00", "17:08", "17:16", "17:24", "17:32", "17:40", "17:48", "17:56", "18:04", "18:12",
        "18:20", "18:28", "18:36", "18:44", "18:51", "19:00", "19:10", "19:20", "19:30", "19:39", "19:50", 
        "20:03", "20:16", "20:30", "20:43", "20:56", "21:10", "21:23", "21:36", "21:50", "22:03", "22:16",
        "22:30", "22:43", "22:56", "23:10", "23:23", "23:36"};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dayfragment, container, false);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, time);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    Time now = new Time();
    now.set(now);
    return view;
}}
```

--fragment.xml

```
public class DayFragment extends ListFragment {
String[] time = new String[] { "06:30","06:40","06:48","06:56","07:04","07:12","07:20","07:28","07:36", "07:44",
        "07:52", "08:00", "08:08", "08:16", "08:22", "08:31", "08:40", "08:50", "09:00", "09:10", "09:20",
        "09:30", "09:40", "09:50", "10:00", "10:10", "10:20", "10:30", "10:40", "10:50", "11:00", "11:10",
        "11:20", "11:30", "11:40", "11:50", "12:00", "12:10", "12:20", "12:30", "12:40", "12:50", "13:00",
        "13:10", "13:20", "13:30", "13:40", "13:50", "14:00", "14:10", "14:20", "14:30", "14:40", "14:50",
        "15:00", "15:10", "15:20", "15:30", "15:40", "15:50", "16:00", "16:10", "16:20", "16:30", "16:40", 
        "16:50", "17:00", "17:08", "17:16", "17:24", "17:32", "17:40", "17:48", "17:56", "18:04", "18:12",
        "18:20", "18:28", "18:36", "18:44", "18:51", "19:00", "19:10", "19:20", "19:30", "19:39", "19:50", 
        "20:03", "20:16", "20:30", "20:43", "20:56", "21:10", "21:23", "21:36", "21:50", "22:03", "22:16",
        "22:30", "22:43", "22:56", "23:10", "23:23", "23:36"};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dayfragment, container, false);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, time);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    Time now = new Time();
    now.set(now);
    return view;
}}
```

--text_fragment.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#5ba4e5"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="40px"
     android:textColor="#040404"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/time"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudo code for a novice:

```
 GET your current time -> Time CURRENT_TIME = new Time();
```

Now you have to find the nearest Time with the values of your `time[]`. So you are looking for the index where

```
 //exact the same time
 time[index] EQUAL CURRENT_TIME  

 OR

 //your current time has to be between your time tables
 time[index] is smaller to CURRENT_TIME &&  time[index+1] is bigger to CURRENT_TIME
```

In the `Time` object you have the functions `after`,`before` and `compare` ([Java:Time](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html#compare(android.text.format.Time,%20android.text.format.Time)))

Be careful with `time[index+1]` and `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`. At this point you have to check if `time[index+1]` exists. If not, the last time value is the one you are looking for

Comment: for me does not turn out. you did not could to me examples to write a source code.

Comment: that you wrote me, I that did not understand.